# Media Query overwritten

Tags: css, media-queries

When the width of my screen is in mobile 375px wide, line 3005 padding seems to override padding on lines 2288 and 965. My media queries are at the end of my CSS.

Why would the wrong media query be selected and how do I fix it? I am expecting it to select line 2288.

#CSS

```
line 965
.Cards-sec {        
  background-color: #0C304C;
  padding: 0px 0px 100px;
}

line 2288
  @media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
.ran-sec, .Cards-sec {
 padding: 70px 0px 50px;
}

line 3005
  @media screen and (max-width: 992px)   
.Cards-sec {
  padding: 0px 45px 45px 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottom media query will overwrite the two paddings before on *all* screens that are less than 992px wide. You have to put them in a different order: Place the second mq after the third one.

Comment: Do I need to go from widest to narrowest?

Comment: If you only use `max-width` as the condition, yes. Else the wider will overwrite the narrower one, like in your case.